# Nautilus - bypass trash by default

Tags: nautilus, trash

The title says it all. I know I can do <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove files bypassing the trash.

What I want, is to just hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> and bypass the trash by default. <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> should be to remove to trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw this... might be up your alley:

https://github.com/vitaut/captain-nemo

Looks like there is the Shift Delete already configured in this example (referring to this image: https://raw.github.com/vitaut/captain-nemo/master/img/keyboard-shortcuts-dialog.png).

Good luck.